# Text doesn't center in TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I'm trying to center the Text in a TextView in a TableLayout but somehow it isn't working in installed App. It may be caused by the width that I set to 0dp. I did this to get the table weights working correctly.

**This is the XML-Layout for the Activity:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_sign_in"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Log in with..."
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_account"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/text_sign_in"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_logo_instagram"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/acc_image_margin_start"
            android:contentDescription="Profile Image"
            android:elevation="@dimen/acc_image_elevation"
            android:outlineProvider="bounds"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_instagram" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_instagram_label"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="@string/label_instagram"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_instagram_login"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:drawableLeft="@color/color_youtube"
            android:text="Log In"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_logo_twitter"
            android:contentDescription="Profile Image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_twitter"
            android:elevation="@dimen/acc_image_elevation"
            android:outlineProvider="bounds"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/acc_image_margin_start"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_twitter_label"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="@string/label_twitter"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"/>



     <com.maximutan.socialmedia_feed_merger.widgets.CustomTwitterLoginButton
            android:id="@+id/button_twitter_login"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="Log In"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_logo_twitch"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/acc_image_margin_start"
            android:contentDescription="Profile Image"
            android:elevation="@dimen/acc_image_elevation"
            android:outlineProvider="bounds"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_twitch" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_twitch_label"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="@string/label_twitch"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_twitch_login"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:drawableLeft="@color/color_youtube"
            android:text="Log In"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_logo_facebook"
            android:contentDescription="Profile Image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_facebook"
            android:elevation="@dimen/acc_image_elevation"
            android:outlineProvider="bounds"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/acc_image_margin_start"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_facebook_label"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="@string/label_facebook"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_facebook_login"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:drawableLeft="@color/color_youtube"
            android:text="Log In"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

**This is what the Activity looks in the Android Studio Editor:**

[image: Editor View]

**This is what the Activity looks after Executing:**

[image]

**EDIT**

I recognized that sometimes after reopening the running app after the while the problem is gone and the text is displayed correctly like in this image what makes me wonder if it has something to do with the code beyond that I execute after unpausing the activity

[image: Screenshot 2]

```
//CHECK TOKEN VALIDITY AFTER THE LOGIN IS FINISHED
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    refreshLayout();
}

//REFRESHES LAYOUT AFTER INTERNAL CHANGES
private void refreshLayout(){
    if(NetworkManager.getInstance().isValid(ConstantsHelper.ID_INSTAGRAM)){
        mInstagramButton.setText(getString(R.string.button_signed_in));
        mInstagramButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_text_secondary_light));
        mInstagramButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_done, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    if(NetworkManager.getInstance().isValid(ConstantsHelper.ID_TWITCH)){
        mTwitchButton.setText(getString(R.string.button_signed_in));
        mTwitchButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_text_secondary_light));
        mTwitchButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_done, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    if(NetworkManager.getInstance().isValid(ConstantsHelper.ID_FACEBOOK)){
        mFacebookButton.setText(getString(R.string.button_signed_in));
        mFacebookButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_text_secondary_light));
        mFacebookButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_done, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    if(NetworkManager.getInstance().isValid(ConstantsHelper.ID_TWITTER)){
        mTwitterButton.setText(getString(R.string.button_signed_in));
        mTwitterButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_text_secondary_light));
        mTwitterButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_done, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: `TextView` is not inside `TableLayout`?

Comment: @Yupi I'm talking about the TextViews and Buttons in the TableLayout

Comment: Try to surround `TextView` with `LinearLayout` and to `LinearLayout` put:
`android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"`
and for `TextView` use `match_parent` for width and height and then gravity put `center`

Comment: @Yupi Ok I'll try that

Comment: @Yupi Yep that seems to work. Write your comment into an answer and I mark it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution for your problem is to surround `TexTview` with `LinearLayout` and give it the width and height of your `TextView` like:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="0.4"
```

Then you can use `match_parent` for width and height for `TextView`. That will give you possibility to manipulate with `gravity`. So you will be able to set `gravity` of `TextView` to `centre`.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the gravity to center eg. `android:gravity="center"` instead `android:gravity="center_vertical"`